# use hardcoded string concatenated with a value from dataset in ImageButton tooltip

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tooltip, imagebutton

I have w grid that contains an ImageButton. I want to set the tooltip from aspx page, something like:

```
The user's id is <user_id> and his name is <user_name>
```

where `user_id` and `user_name` are fields in grid's dataset. How to achieve this?Here is my code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewUser" runat="server" ToolTip=' <%# Eval("user_id") %>'
                                                        AlternateText="View or edit the record" ImageUrl="~/images/Icon/view_text.png"
                                                        CommandName="ViewOrder" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most maintainable is using codebehind, `RowDataBound` is the best place:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton btnViewUser = (ImageButton) e.Row.FindControl("btnViewUser");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        btnViewUser.Tooltip = string.Format("The user's id is {0} and his name is {1}"
            , row.Field<int>("user_id")
            , row.Field<string>("user_name"));
    }
}
```

Here is the aspx approach(not sure if that works, i would never use code like this):

```
<asp:ImageButton id="btnViewUser" runat="server"
           Tooltip='<%# "The users id is "+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "user_id") +" and his name is "+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "user_name") +"" %>'
           AlternateText="View or edit the record" 
           ImageUrl="~/images/Icon/view_text.png"
           CommandName="ViewOrder" 
           CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
```

Comment: But I want to achieve this in aspx file, as stated above

Comment: something like Tooltip = ' <%# Eval("user_id") %>' but concatenated with my hardcoded string and with the other value

Comment: I've updated the question and added source code

Comment: This worked, I just had to escape the character '. Thanks.

Comment: @gabi: How? Then i can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've replaced ' with &#39;